# Putting an array value into a string in powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I was having difficulty understanding how String values work with arrays in powershell. I wanted to know the correct syntax for placing an array into a string. Currently, this is what I am trying. The square brackets seem to be registered as part of the string rather than the variable.

```
$array = @(2,3,5)

$string = " I have $array[2] apples"
```

This outputs:  `I have 2 3 5[2] apples`

Comment: Use $($array[2]) the $() runs whatever is inside as powershell

Comment: There's also the `-f` operator; e.g.: `"I have {0} apples" -f $array[2]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `[2]` is being read as a string. Use `$($array[2])` in order to run that part as powershell.

```
$array = @(2,3,5)

"I have $($array[2]) apples"
```

This outputs `I have 5 apples`.

In the comments you asked how to do a for loop for this.

In powershell you should pipe whenever you can, the pipe command is `|`

```
@(2,3,5) | foreach-object{
    "I have $_ apples"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if this would also apply to $(array[$i]) where $i is the variable declared by a for loop.

Comment: I answered your comment in the solution

Comment: @J.Tam answer your question from comment yourself `$array = @(2,3,5);for($i=0;$i -le 2;$i++){"I have $($array[$i]) apples"}`

Comment: For in-memory collections I suggest not recommending use of the pipeline, at least not without explaining the performance implications.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but what might those performance implications be? I typically use C#, but am doing some PowerShell right now and was about to just do a for loop as I normally would, but came across this answer and was going to use the above "PowerShell way" and pipe it, but then I saw this comment, and now I don't know what I should use.

Comment: @MostHated There is a performance hit when you use Linq because it has overhead.
 Here is a example...If I measure how long it takes to cycle through a array of 1000 objects. ForEach-Object takes 64 milliseconds, ForEach() takes 16 milliseconds and For() takes 2 milliseconds

Comment: Ah, I understand. While I should have, I didn't realize that using pipe methods like that would end up being Linq. Definitely glad that I do know that for sure now, so thanks.